# Peer reset connection when trying to access some websites

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have issues trying to access some websites (github.com & mail.protonmail.com).
With Firefox I get a `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR`. After waiting some time (can be 5 minutes, can be more), the error goes away and I can access the website again.
I notice this started to happened when I started to use my iPhone as a hotspot.

[image]

I tried to ping the websites not working and this is what I get :

```
ING github.com (84.103.237.61) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from swacs.n9uf.net (84.103.237.61): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=38.5 ms
64 bytes from swacs.n9uf.net (84.103.237.61): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=46.7 ms
64 bytes from swacs.n9uf.net (84.103.237.61): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=45.6 ms

--- github.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 38.492/43.611/46.718/3.647 ms
```

Comment: Have you tried using an alternative browser and flushing your browser caches?

Comment: @davidgo yes, same result on Chrome

Comment: Check if the time of your OS is correct